# Logic of intuition vs. logic as algebra in mathematical axioms

Tags: logic, epistemology

In maths we have a set of axioms for addition, multiplication or whatever, for a certain system. What can been said about the possibility of logic, which validates the axioms in the context say of actual addition and multiplication (meta axioms), as intuitive concepts, rather than of 'logic as algebra' of arbitrary (or non intuitive) axioms?

Comment: What are you usking is quite unclear; what does it mean "a logical description which validates the axioms in the context of say addition and multiplication (meta axioms) being intuitive concepts" ?

Comment: The question needs clarification. Are you asking if there are axiomatisations of first order logic? (Yes of course) Or are you asking if arithmetic can be entirely grounded in 1st order logic without new axioms? (No it can't). Or are you asking about grounding logic in arithmetic rather than the converse?

Answer (score 3):

Almost all axioms in mathematics have been validated as intuitive concepts before efforts are undertaken to define them logically.  For instance, the Greeks axiomatically believed there were no irrational numbers partly because the lack thereof allowed them to believe numbers and geometry were inseparable, and that was intuitive at the time.  They held their intuitive belief until someone formally showed that their approach lead to paradox ( Hippasus, presumably).  The axioms for addition and multiplication were based on intuitive needs for day to day life, and only axiomatized later when we wished to use them to solve difficult problems such as those involving infinity.  Even the modern axioms of set theory, which are used in modern mathematics to "prove" nearly everything, were initially founded in the intuitive idea of "a collection of things," and only had to be rigorously defined as a result of that intuitive idea allowing paradoxes into the mathematical constructions in ways that were deemed unacceptable.

In modern day schools, we even teach the intuitive approach in many cases.  Consider calculus.  Derivatives are typically taught intuitively, rather than relying on their formal definition using epsilon-delta proofs.  And the theory behind Common Core, the method of teaching mathematics which is currently taking over America, the goal is to develop a more intuitive understanding of the math first before teaching the abstract versions of that math later.

Comment: @SanchoPanza Rigor is an important part of mathematics, but it's only part of mathematics.  For example, we did arithmetic for hundreds of years before Giuseppe Peano pinned his axioms in the 19th century.  And, of course, Tarski proved that we have to be careful with rigor in 1936, for if the grammar of our discourse is a regular language, it cannot prove its own semantics, so must inescapably be rooted in an *intuitive* acceptance of the meaning the language of mathematics.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/30957/discussion-between-cort-ammon-and-sancho-panza).

Comment: I've deleted a series of comments that seemed to be umm... rather unnecessary to the answer.  At best, they could be construed as a request for sources on something that seems pretty fairly obvious.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, your question concerns two different ways of understanding what logic and mathematics are about. One approach (mathematical platonism) treats axioms as primitively true or obvious and treats theorems as explications of the axioms. Another approach (logicism and perhaps formalism) presents logic and math as being about what are the logical consequences of axioms and rules, independently of their meaning or truth. It is simply a matter of saying - if these axioms then these theorems. The axioms may have an intended interpretation, but it is not required for the logic.

While the intuitive approach is easier to grasp, there is a lot to be said for the latter approach, which is why it is so common. One of the developments that gave rise to it was the invention of non-euclidean geometry. From Euclid's days, the axioms of geometry were considered to be inuitively obvious statements about lines and points. Then a bunch of mathematicians in the 19th century decided to see if was possible to derive the parallel postulate from the other four postulates. One way to do this is to assume it is false and see if that contradicts the other postulates. Hey presto, they found that all kinds of interesting geometries emerge from assuming that the parallel postulate is false and replacing it with a different postulate. Do these other geometries have useful interpretations in the real world? Yes, though this wasn't known at the time. In other words, often it is highly fruitful to free your axioms from an intenteded interpretation and just see where the logic takes you.

As to arithmetic, clearly this has an intended application, but once you start thinking about transfinite numbers, your intuitions will likely desert you, which is why axiomatised accounts of arithmetic are important. Also, note that it is problematic to speak of validating the axioms of arithmetic through some kind of meta axioms. Godel's second incompleteness theorem holds that no axiomatisable system of arithmetic can prove its own consistency, so you would still be left with the problem of proving the consistency of your meta axioms.

Answer (score 1):

Intuition is important in mathematics; unfortunately this does not come across in how mathematics is often presented, or taught.

Counting - what could be simpler; and then you see the definition of Peano Arithmetic...

Or then, the geometry of lines, spheres and cubes; and then you see the axioms of Euclidean or Lobachevskian Geometry...

The axiomatic method is a tool of mathematics, but not to be identified with it - which unfortunately happens; it's rather like a novel being identified with the pen by which it was written.

That said, as a tool, it's useful -  why? Because it reduces the number of elements to look at, and clarifies the dependencies amongst them.

Answer (score 0):

What you are asking was the subject of a famous debate at the dawn of modern logic, [between Frege and Hilbert](http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/frege-hilbert/#DeeDis), a precursor of the modern debate between mathematical realism and structuralism. Hilbert advocated axioms as implicit definitions of terms occuring in them:"*concept can be fixed logically only by its relations to other concepts. These relations, formulated in certain statements I call axioms, thus arriving at the view that axioms… are the definitions of the concepts*". To Frege on the other hand, concepts come from the domain under consideration and are given in advance, and axioms simply codify some relations that hold in that domain, but the domain itself is inexhausted by them, and in principle inexhaustible. Based on this notion he criticized Hilbert's independence and consistency proofs. See Shapiro's [Categories, Structures, and the Frege-Hilbert Controversy](http://philmat.oxfordjournals.org/content/13/1/61.full) for more on the Frege-Hilbert debate and its modern implications, and [Buzaglo's Logic of Concept Expansion](https://books.google.com/books?id=NNO3b3-9zu4C&dq=godel+axioms+forced+on+us&source=gbs_navlinks_s) for a modern view of conceptual realism.

According to Frege, Hilbert's axiomatic geometry is a general theory of which Euclidean geometry is a special case. That Hilbert can produce models of his general theory, where all axioms but the parallel postulate hold (e.g. the Poincare disk model), does not prove that the parallel postulate is independent in the special case of Euclidean geometry. The concept of Euclidean line is not exhausted by Hilbert's axioms, says Frege, so Hilbert's models disregard the meaning of "line" ("lines" are some circular arcs in the Poincare disk). Therefore his independence proofs do not apply to Euclidean geometry proper, and do not prove that the parallel postulate is independent.

The same goes for consistency. Consistency of a special theory would imply consistency of a general theory that it is an example of, but it doesn't work the other way. It is perfectly possible for a general theory to have a consistent example, as well as an inconsistent one. Therefore, Hilbert's analytic models for Euclidean geometry do not prove its consistency either, even if we assume that analytic geometry is consistent "point" and "pair of coordinates" are different concepts. Consistency of analytic geometry does imply consistency of Hilbert's axiomatic geometry, but not of Euclidean geometry.

On Frege's view if a sentence is formally deducible from a set of axioms then it is logically entailed by them, but if it is not deducible does not mean that it is not entailed nonetheless. Frege tried to work out his semantic notions of independence and consistency, and in some ways anticipated the work of Tarski.  Later Gödel expressed similar view of set theory as inexhausted by ZFC axioms, and argued that the continuum hypothesis, proved independent in the Hilbert's sense by Cohen, might nonetheless get resolved because new "*axioms force themselves upon us as being true*".